# Postgresql volume with supervisor

Tags: postgresql, docker, supervisord

There is a custom dockerfile with a supervisor for postgresql, a supervisor for ssh and postgres services. I need to throw pg_data on the host, but when I write volume /pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/11/main postgres in the compose, it cannot start. Can you tell me what is the problem?The error is INFO exited: postgresql (exit status 1; not expected)

Comment: you need to post docker-compose.yml and the commands you are running in order to understand what you are doing

Comment: version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres_supervisor_custom:latest                                      
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: cluster_db_001_slave
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - ./pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/11/main

Comment: it gets truncated. you should update the question with this information

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including your Compose setup, the Dockerfile, and the complete startup error ("exit status 1" just means "it didn't work").  For the use case you're describing you shouldn't need supervisord, it should be enough to run PostgreSQL in its own container and maybe even use the standard `postgres` image - you shouldn't need to make an ssh connection into your database server.